# centos default apache log location for virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mod-wsgi

may i know what is the default location for the error logs for inidividual sites/virtualhost in `apache` + `centos`? Also, if I want to customize the location of the log file, do I define `errorLog` under the `VirtualHost` in `http.conf` (can't seem to get it working)

Answer (score 0):

The httpd logs files are located by default under `/var/log/httpd` in CentOS.

Yes, you can add ErrorLog in your virtual host to specify a different error log file for that VH.